# How do I make sure markdown doesn't appear when listing posts in a blog?

Tags: django

I'm building a blog using Django and I just integrated markdown. How do I make sure that the truncated part of the body of a post (which is telling a little of what you'll see when that particular post is opened) doesn't display markdown?

I created a template filter `markdown`:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django import template
import markdown

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='markdown')
def markdown_format(text):
    return mark_safe(markdown.markdown(text))
```

Here's the usage in the `post_list.html` template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load blog_tags static disqus_tags %}
{% disqus_dev %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="heading-font">Shelter At Your Crossroads</h1>
        <p class="lead">...some random ass text that could serve as motto or something</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                {% if tag %}
                    <h2 class="mb-4">Posts tagged with "{{ tag.name }}"</h2>
                {% endif %}
                {% for post in posts %}
                    <div class="card mb-5">
                        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ post.image.url }}" alt="{{ post.title }}">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h2 class="card-title"><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
                            <p class="card-text">{{ post.body|markdown|truncatewords_html:50 }}</p>
                            <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Read More </a>
                            <a href="{% url 'post_share' post.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Share Post</a>
                            <div class="float-right">                     
                                <i class="fa fa-tags"></i>
                                {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
                                    <a href="{% url 'post_list_by_tag' tag.slug %}">
                                        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-info">{{ tag.name }}</span>
                                    </a>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>        
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer text-center text-muted">
                            Posted on {{ post.publish.date }} by <a href="#">{{ post.author.get_full_name }}</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="card border-dark mb-3">
                    <div class="card-header">Post Count</div>
                    <div class="card-body text-dark">
                        <h4 class="card-title text-center">Total Number of Posts</h4>
                        <p class="card-text text-center display-3">{% total_posts %}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card border-dark mb-3">
                    <div class="card-header">Latest Posts</div>
                    <div class="card-body text-dark">
                        <h4 class="card-title text-center">Most Recent Posts</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">{% show_latest_posts 3 %}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card border-dark mb-3">
                    <div class="card-header">Latest Comments</div>
                    <div class="card-body text-dark">
                        <h4 class="card-title text-center">Most Recent Comments</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">{% disqus_recent_comments shortname 5 50 1 %}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>                      
            </div>
        </div>
        {% include 'includes/pagination.html' with page=posts %}        
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The filter was used on line 22 - **{{ post.body|markdown|truncatewords_html:50 }}**

How do I make display just normal text?

Comment: hi, you mean you type *<b>test</b>* and you want to display it as normal text?

Comment: I kinda wanna skip headings and subheadings

Comment: try this filter *|safe* like this *post.body|safe*

Comment: First, I can't truncate because safe only takes one argument. It also displays level 1 heading raw - I mean instead of displaying `# Introduction`  as a level 1 heading, it displays it as raw text